# Converting Django App to DRF App

Tags: django

I have a django app that is not live yet and I just got a request to use API and i ended up selecting DRF. But am really lost on some of its components. I was able to login, get token and pass the token to get something.  It will use angular.as on front end now, which needs all to be JSON.

While i will rewrite the views, i want to reuse as much as possible especially modules. E.g. I have a validation that validates registration of forms (it used from three different views because a member can be registered in three different ways with some conditions applied i.e. self-registration, company registration and company-agent registration).

```
def validate_member(data,editing=False,directregistration=True):
     #data is passsed from forms.py. Return any error message and the cleaned data to the calling forms.py
     return [errmsg,data]
```

forms.py clean method example:

```
  class NewMemberForm(forms.Form):
  firstName=forms.CharField(max_length=25,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput())

def clean(self):

    self.cleaned_data=super(NewMemberForm,self).clean()

    validate_member_form=validate_member(self.cleaned_data,directregistration=True)

    #do we have error messages now?

    if len(validate_member_form[0])>0: #yes we have error messages
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(validate_member_form[0]),code='invalid')

    return validate_member_form[1]
```

and my views.py:

```
    if request.method=='POST':

    err_found=False
    go_id=''

    form=NewMemberForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
     #create user
     pass
```

I see forms.py is useless in DRF APIView (i failed to get an example at least). How do I convert such an app without so much pain?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing - you can't (at the very least not easily). DRF programmers have decided to implement `serializers` as completely different still parallel structure from `django forms`. Infact they don't even share any ancestory. You can certainly share code in forms and serializers using mixins, but then again there are subtle differences like `forms` have `clean` methods, while serializers have `validate` ones.

Here are the few strategies that can be adopted to minimize the code repetition -

1. **Skinny views and fat models** - Try to keep most of the business logic either in models (if they are related to models), or in separate domain classes. Views should just be a connection between your models and templates, and shouldn't contain business or model related logic. This way the code you write can be reused among django's normal views and DRF views. If you want to take this a little further, try to encapsulate global validations and constraints (i.e. the validations that always holds true) at model level, and then you can write certain serializer mixins that catch validation error from models and display it to user.
2. **Service Oriented Architecture** - Try to write everything as services or REST APIs, and use those services in your normal views. My company had certain performance concerns, so I end up writing a custom request client (on the lines of django test client) that doesn't actually make an http request to an api, but still provides adequate abstraction. This approach might seem lucrative at first, but in long term it creates really messy code. Infact if you are willing to go to such extents, I'd recommend the next approach.
3. **Frontend framework** - Provided you don't have certain SEO constraints, then  you can certainly move to frontend javascript framework based architecture. Then you only need to write DRF APIs, and all the other code should be handled by client framework. It also accounts for better user experience.

Comment: Thanks @hspandher. It sounds like a rewrite is a high probability. If i may ask, how would this GET would become in APIView.

login_required
def my_activities(request,asso_id):
my_activities=AssociationActivity.objects.annotate(act_id=F('id'),act_name=F('activity__name')).values('act_id','act_name').filter(association_id=asso_id)
  my_activities_listed=list(my_activities)
  activities=Activity.objects.values('id','name').filter(active='Active')
  actvities_listed=list(activities)
  reply={'my_activites':my_activities_listed,'activities':actvities_listed} data=json.dumps(reply)

Comment: @NieSelam Sorry what 'GET' are you referring to?

Comment: Any idea @hspandher?